# Accessing a MySQL Database Every Page Access

Tags: php, mysql, database

It's more of a general question really. I am using WordPress and I have a custom PHP script that checks if the "Expiry Date" of a user has not occurred yet in my MySQL user table.

So basically allowing them to continue to view the 'support' page if they haven't expired.

Now, I perform this query *every time* the user accesses this page, and the reason I do all this is because I have another piece of software accessing the same table which they can receive these support files for if they haven't expired yet.

Is this very bad practice? If so, what would be a better solution?

Comment: You could set a session variable the first time, and use that instead of checking the database every time.

Comment: Are you doing this only on every login, like your title says, or on every page access, like you say in the question?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to edit the title. Will amend. It is every time the page is accessed, and a session variable would be a good idea actually. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: That said, a simple query like this should have a negligible load on the database.

Comment: Ahh I see. I guess technology has far progressed since the time we had to care about things like this eh? :p Regardless, trying to ensure I'm using good practice where I can is a good thing I suppose. Though in this case, it may simply be fine to leave it as it is and save the effort if it's not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the information can be updated on the DB by an admin or the "Expiry Date" can be altered by something else other than time... then you're doing the right thing.

If you are just tracking a "natural" expiration, I'd suggest that you use $_SESSION (more info here: [Session Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)) and save a bunch of unnecessary queries.

Comment: Yes it's a field manually edited by admins. I was just wondering if I was sending too many queries to the database. Saying that, I only expect about 40-80 members accessing the support site at maximum in any one day.